# How to partition this object?

Tags: geometry

I was given an exercise in which my task is to partition this geometric object into 16 equal pieces(both by area and shape). How can someone accomplish this task?

EDIT: We also need to partition the inside.

[image]

Comment: Do you have some details about the dimensions of geometric object?

Comment: Not very many, I only know that this object is 2 dimensional, everything else is in the picture above.

Comment: I think the solution is four of these back to back:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420433/is-there-more-than-one-way-to-divide-the-l-shaped-tromino-into-four-congruent/1442518#1442518

Comment: @McLinux You might want to consider whether or not the thick perimeter is important. If it is, I recommend stating it in the question. If it's not, I recommend re-drawing the image to exclude it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but I think this is a valid solution: ?!

[image]

Comment: evidently it is :)

Comment: @uniquesolution Well, I wasn't sure if we were supposed to partition the area inside as well for example.

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure they did mean the area enclosed, but I like your solution :)

Comment: Yeah, this is a very nice solution, but i think we were supposed to also partition the inside.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This is not really a solution, because of the specific dimensions of the shape in the question. See comments.

---

I'm not sure if this is a valid solution, it depends on the dimensions of the object. But if your object is essentially four squares cut out of the corner of a big square, the following works:

[image]

I base my solution heavily on another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420433/is-there-more-than-one-way-to-divide-the-l-shaped-tromino-into-four-congruent/1442518#1442518) about the L-tromino.

Comment: But the dimensions don't work. The missing corners aren't a quarter of the whole thing. Also, you are treating the outside and inside the same. (I don't know if this is allowed though)

Comment: @Alex Yes, I'm not sure if this is allowed, but the rules for partitioning aren't clear, so I'm posting it as a possibility. Also, the missing corners, by my crude finger measurements, do seem to be a quarter of the whole area... are you sure they're not?

Comment: Well, the whole thing is 11 blocks wide and the corners are only 2 blocks wide.

Comment: @Alex yes good point. I'll make a note of that in my answer.

Comment: @Alex, you might also want to consider whether or not the thick perimeter is important. If it is, I recommend stating it in the question. If it's not, I recommend re-drawing the image to exclude it.

Comment: @ColdBhandal I didn't ask the question, but yes, I think McLinux should clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @Alex- you are right indeed. You both have an 'x' in your name, which threw me off. I'll put my comment in the main question.