# Can a L-shaped figure be divided into 5 congruent shapes?

Tags: geometry, symmetry, congruences-geometry

Given a square, remove one quarter of it. Can the resulting L-shaped figure be divided into 5 congruent shapes? If not, how can we prove that fact?

I tried using circles, triangles and smaller squares, but could not find a solution. Is there a known general solution for any number of divisions, not just 5?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. 
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts 
and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, 
and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Related, but with four congruent pieces http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420433/is-there-more-than-one-way-to-divide-the-l-shaped-tromino-into-four-congruent/1442518#1442518

Comment: Hi. Yesterday I noticed at page’s tab your [question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41046/what-kind-of-pleasure-is-the-one-we-get-by-pursuing-mathematical-problems-and-so) on pleasure and satisfaction by doing mathematics. I guess that you can be interested in a point of view of a mathematician, especially taking into account that that thread contains no accepted answers. So I wrote a short note (in Word) for you and put it [here](https://mega.nz/file/9lgDxDAb#arABeM4b_qEvucpXt-RjrQd5GejR6QX7V6n6amFXRgg). I hope it can help you at your way.

Comment: Alex, Many thanks for sharing your thinking and research on this topic. It will certainly help me on my way forward.